# How to Save/Restore while reading subset of data during training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want an efficient way to save the training process given a subset of data that are read, then load a new subset of data and continue the training from the same spot that was saved. How to save/load model properly to do that?

I have already tried many different ways of saving/restoring model I found but I get confused, with all because there are changes depended on the version.

```
def train(self,sess,iter):
    start_time = time.clock()

    n_early_stop_epochs = 10  # Define it
    n_epochs = 30  # Define it

    # restore variables from previous train session
    if(iter>0): restore_variables(sess)

    # create saver object
    saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list = tf.trainable_variables(), max_to_keep = 4)

    early_stop_counter = 0

    # initialize train variables
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    sess.run(init_op)

    # assign a large value to min
    min_valid_loss = sys.float_info.max
    epoch=0

    # loop for a given number of epochs
    while (epoch < n_epochs): # max num epoch iteration
        epoch += 1
        epoch_start_time = time.clock()

        train_loss = self.train_epoch(sess)
        valid_loss = self.valid_epoch(sess)
        # print("valid ends")
        epoch_end_time=time.clock()
        if (epoch % 10 == 0):
            info_str ='Epoch='+str(epoch) + ', Train: ' + str(train_loss) + ', Valid: '
            info_str += str(valid_loss) + ', Time=' +str(epoch_end_time - epoch_start_time)
            print(info_str)

        if valid_loss < min_valid_loss:
            print('Best epoch=' + str(epoch))
            save_variables(sess, saver, epoch, self.model_id)
            min_valid_loss = valid_loss
            early_stop_counter = 0
        else:
            early_stop_counter += 1


        # stop training when overfiiting conditon is true
        if early_stop_counter > n_early_stop_epochs:
            # too many consecutive epochs without surpassing the best model
            print('stopping early')
            # self.kill = True
            break
    end_time=time.clock()
    print('Total time = ' + str(end_time - start_time))
```

I have a for-loop for reading data from disk to memory (read a subset), train on this subset data, 
I keep a variable

```
  iter = 0 # counter, a number for current loop
```

to know that in every other loop except first one we load the model first.
Everything seems to work but I am not sure that training variables continue to be updated from the last checkpoint or starts from zero again. Because my training loss is almost zero in a few epochs while the validation loss doesn't converge from one subset to another, after all, data have been read, validation loss may take values from 0.3 to 7 per subset of data.

For example *first loop--fist subset* of a data ***training_loss =0.0004***. ***validation_loss=0.34*** for a number of epochs, 
in the next iteration of data ***training_loss=0.0000***, ***validation_loss=5.2*** and so on. Validation_loss have peaks and downs, *doesn't converge*.

Comment: If you are not sure your process behaves as you want it to, I recommend you create a toy dataset to test it with. Grab a dataset that will continue to improve, checkpoint it in the middle, and then find out if it carries on or starts over.

Comment: I have a CNN architecture, with one, "with tf.variable_scope("model_architecture", reuse=reuse):" and below that is the code of the network.
If you want to see code of save/restore let me know

Comment: I don't, thanks. Just wanted to offer an idea how you could investigate your own question.